I want to download files from the Aws S3 bucket in zip
I have a AWS s3 bucket with the files. and when i provide file ids i want to download that files in the zip.
im using nodejs as backend and nextjs as a front end how to do it.
currently in the backend it is working but when big size of files are downloading in the front end it say time out error. Current flow in the backend is files are getting in the backend and then it is zipping and send to the front end to download.
i have increase the timing in the server config but no improvements.
 const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open(method, url, true);
     xhr.responseType = 'blob';
     xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
     xhr.setRequestHeader('x-access-token', `${createJWTToken()}`);

     xhr.send(JSON.stringify(dataBody));

     xhr.onprogress = function (e) {
         if (e.lengthComputable) {
          const progress = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
             setProgress(Math.ceil(progress));
         }
     };

     xhr.onload = function (e) {
         if (this.status === 200) {
           const blob = new Blob([this.response], { type: 'application/zip' });
           const urls = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
           const link = document.createElement('a');
           link.href = urls;
           link.setAttribute('download', `FileDrop-${Date.now()}.zip`);
           document.body.appendChild(link);
           link.click();
           link.remove();
     }
};

I want to download big size of files.

"Server config", please share that

From your description, you can try to set the client xhr timeout value to zero.


xhr.timeout = 0



Considering you used AWS s3 on your node.js backend using the aws-sdk package. You can have the setup configured as shown below:


const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

const s3 = new AWS.S3({
  httpOptions: {
    timeout: 1800000, // Timeout in milliseconds (30 minutes)
    connectTimeout: 10000 // Connection timeout (10 seconds)
  }
});



The timeout value set here is 30 minutes, you can increase it based on your preference.
I hope I have been able to help.
